# Precedes Or Not Equal To Symbol

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

This question is related to [Element of or Equal To Symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213781/element-of-or-equal-to-symbol) and [Creating a \precneq symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58884/creating-a-precneq-symbol).

From those pages, I learned about the `mathabx` package and its `\precneq` symbol. However I noticed that it uses a modified version of the `\prec` symbol. *It isn't a replica of the standard `\prec` symbol*. Instead it uses a modified version of `\prec`.

I've been trying to research how to construct a math symbol that's a modification of either `\prec` or `\preceq` but to no avail. Does anyone have solution/advice?

The solution in [Element of or Equal To Symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213781/element-of-or-equal-to-symbol) is extremely nice (I prefer the "roundcap bar" version); More generally is there a general procedure for making such "or not equal to" symbols from already defined binary operators?

Comment: These are not exactly the same but you might still want to take a look at `\precneqq` or `\npreceqq` or `\npreceq` from the package `pxfonts` or `ptfonts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that builds the underbar with the help of picture mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pnrelbar}{%
  \linethickness{\dimen2}%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\prec$}%
  \dimen@=1.1\ht\z@
  \begin{picture}(\dimen@,.4ex)
  \roundcap
  \put(0,.2ex){\line(1,0){\dimen@}}
  \put(\dimexpr 0.5\dimen@-.2ex\relax,0){\line(1,1){.4ex}}
  \end{picture}%
}

\newcommand{\precneq}{\mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{\text{\prec@neq}}}}}
\newcommand{\prec@neq}{%
  \dimen2=\f@size\dimexpr.04pt\relax
  \oalign{%
    \noalign{\kern\dimexpr.2ex-.5\dimen2\relax}
    $\m@th\prec$\cr
    \noalign{\kern-.5\dimen2}
    \hidewidth\pnrelbar\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\alpha\precneq\beta_{\precneq}$ $\prec\preceq\precneq$

$\alpha\preceq\beta_{\preceq}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is some dirty messing of egreg's excellent solution. It is very *raw* and needs emergency treatment in ICU.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\precneq}{\mathrel{\text{\prec@eq}}}
\newcommand{\prec@eq}{%
  \oalign{%
    \hidewidth$\m@th\prec$\hidewidth\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern1ex}%
    $\m@th\smash{\Neq}$\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-.5ex}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\Neq}{\raisebox{0.65ex}{\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\nshortmid$}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\alpha\precneq\beta_{\precneq}$
\end{document}
```

[image]